# Vintage 70's Bike info?

Tags: road-bike, touring, vintage

I was given a vintage touring bike recently. It's steer tube badge says D-114 made in Japan. I can't find any info on it and was hoping someone may have some info on the brand or bike.[image] [image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a serial number imprinted anywhere? (bottom of head tube, below bottom bracket, near dropouts are common locations)

Comment: there is on the seat tube. It is a little hard to read, but looks like 4 Japanese symbols and then 439

Comment: I think those are not japanese symbols but in the latin alphabet (the last 4 digits are probably 22439). Inspect every inch of the frame for other markings. Also, what are all the components on it?

Comment: Cool bike. How do you know it is 70s? Is there a non-vintage 70?

Comment: It could very well be _R22439. I stripped the entire bike when I cleaned and fixed it up. No other markings on it. Components are all Shimano 333 (Thunderbird Front Der., Lark Rear Der.) Everything else is stamped 333 (Hubs, shifters, etc.) I dated the derailleurs to somewhere around early 70's.

Comment: I saved it from a guy who was throwing it away. All he could remember was he bought it new when he was just a kid from a bike shop in Canada.

Comment: @Blam - The cottered cranks place it, I think, prior to about 1980.

Comment: That is a gorgeous bike.  Someone was throwing it away?  Idiot!   You did the right thing to save it, even if you sell it on ebay.  Someone will enjoy it.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a [Nishiki Arrow Speed](http://www.cykelhobby.com/nishbild.htm)

I had one of those while in college in the early 90s.

Answer (score 1):

I have two bikes VERY similar to yours; same components, brakes, fork crown...  One of them has no branding on it. The other is branded "Cobra" and says "made for Eaton's". Eaton's was a Canadian department store chain. Did some research; Raleigh England made the bikes under the brand Cobra for sale at Eaton's. So, your D-114 may actually have been made by Raleigh.

Answer (score 0):

thats a beautiful bike i had a 1962bottechia with the exact components as well as the location of serial numbers also on most vintage bikes that. have stamped markings around center of rear hub you may notice two small numbers seperate from any other markings stamped into center those two lonely numbers are the last two digits of the year it was built thats if those rims are original for that frame

Comment: Welcome to [Bicycles.SE] @francine. Your post would be easier to read with capitalization and perhaps a paragraph break here and there :-)